# How can I display all fonts on one screen size?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, fonts, display

I want to test the font like this. On my machine, there are 270 fonts but I can't not display them all one one screen size so I can only print each time 50 fonts. How can I display it as in the image below?

```
fontlist = FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]];
Panel@Row[fontlist[[1 ;; 50]] /.
   Rule[x_, y_] :> 
    Style[ToString@"Font Test  - " <>   x  , 14, FontFamily -> y], " \ 
     [FilledSquare] " "\n"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Panel @ 
 Multicolumn[Row[{"■ ", #}] & /@ (fontlist[[1 ;; 50]] /. 
     Rule[x_, y_] :> Style[ToString@"Font Test  - " <> x, 14, FontFamily -> y]),
   3, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

```
Panel @ 
 Multicolumn[Row[{"■ ", #}] & /@ 
     (fontlist[[1 ;; 50]] /. Rule[x_, y_] :> 
      Style[ToString@"Font Test  - " <> x, 14, FontFamily -> y]), 
  3, Appearance -> "Horizontal", Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
  Background -> {{{LightBlue, LightOrange}}, Automatic}, 
  Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> White]
```

[image]

You can also [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) the input list and use [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html). If you use [`Scaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) when  setting the option [`ItemSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItemSize.html)  column widths will automatically adjust to the available window width:

```
Panel @ Grid[Partition[Row[{"■ ", #}] & /@ 
   (fontlist[[1 ;; 50]] /. Rule[x_, y_] :> 
       Style[ToString@"Font Test  - " <> x, 14, FontFamily -> y]), 
    2, 2, {1, 1}, {}],
  Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
  ItemSize -> {Scaled[1/2], Automatic}, Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
  Background -> {{{LightBlue, LightOrange}}, Automatic},
  Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> White]
```

[image]

Comment: really nice
I should learn more about Multicolumn